# RabbitMQ restarting consumer in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have this error that repeats in loop until I stop the service:

```
2022-07-05 14:49:48.638  INFO 13544 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Created new connection: connectionFactory#4045fd1f:0/SimpleConnection@2078bf0a [delegate=amqp://people-consumer@107.2.164.186:5672/PEOPLE, localPort= 61087]
2022-07-05 14:49:49.476 ERROR 13544 --- [.2.164.186:5672] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=403, reply-text=ACCESS_REFUSED - access to queue 'qu-people-updates.cores' in vhost 'PEOPLE' refused for user 'people-consumer', class-id=60, method-id=20)
2022-07-05 14:49:49.570  INFO 13544 --- [           main] d.s.p.PeopleToCoreConsumerApplication    : Started PeopleToCoreConsumerApplication in 5891.11 seconds (JVM running for 5892.579)
2022-07-05 14:49:54.653  INFO 13544 --- [ntContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@96dfcbb: tags=[[]], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: PublisherCallbackChannelImpl: AMQChannel(amqp://people-consumer@107.2.164.186:5672/PEOPLE,1), conn: Proxy@64af5454 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@2078bf0a [delegate=amqp://people-consumer@107.2.164.186:5672/PEOPLE, localPort= 61087], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2022-07-05 14:49:55.167 ERROR 13544 --- [.2.164.186:5672] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=403, reply-text=ACCESS_REFUSED - access to queue 'qu-people-updates.cores' in vhost 'PEOPLE' refused for user 'people-consumer', class-id=60, method-id=20)
2022-07-05 14:50:00.352  INFO 13544 --- [ntContainer#0-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@5a2b1d6a: tags=[[]], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: PublisherCallbackChannelImpl: AMQChannel(amqp://people-consumer@107.2.164.186:5672/PEOPLE,2), conn: Proxy@64af5454 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@2078bf0a [delegate=amqp://people-consumer@107.2.164.186:5672/PEOPLE, localPort= 61087], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2022-07-05 14:50:00.850 ERROR 13544 --- [.2.164.186:5672] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=403, reply-text=ACCESS_REFUSED - access to queue 'qu-people-updates.cores' in vhost 'PEOPLE' refused for user 'people-consumer', class-id=60, method-id=20)
2022-07-05 14:50:06.063  INFO 13544 --- [ntContainer#0-3] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@cdfb754: tags=[[]], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: PublisherCallbackChannelImpl: AMQChannel(amqp://people-consumer@107.2.164.186:5672/PEOPLE,3), conn: Proxy@64af5454 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@2078bf0a [delegate=amqp://people-consumer@107.2.164.186:5672/PEOPLE, localPort= 61087], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2022-07-05 14:50:06.548 ERROR 13544 --- [.2.164.186:5672] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=403, reply-text=ACCESS_REFUSED - access to queue 'qu-people-updates.cores' in vhost 'PEOPLE' refused for user 'people-consumer', class-id=60, method-id=20
```

Although the access is refused the queue is created without problems.
Any guess where should I look to find out the problem??

Comment: Look at the permissions for your user (Admin tab on the management console).

Comment: I've checked that, but nothing seems to be wrong. What I don't understand is why I can create a queue but no consume from it. Any idea?

Comment: There are different permissions for configure, read, and write. If you think the user has read permissions, I suggest you ask the rabbit engineering folks on the `rabbitmq-users` Google group - they don't monitor SO closely.